# Can I assign one of my publicly available IP address to my AWS instance?

Tags: ip, ipv4, bgp, aws, arin

I would like to be able to use one of my publicly accessible ip addresses directly with my aws cloud instance. Is there a way I can assign or transfer one of my ip address to aws? My ARIN registry shows I have a block of usable addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS does support [Bring Your Own IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-byoip.html).  You need to establish authority over the address space using RPKI to do it.  Once you've done so, you can complete the remaining steps using the AWS CLI / API.

Comment: As always with BGP announcements, *The most specific IPv4 address range that you can bring is /24.*

Answer (score 2):

As a potential alternative to that, if you have some kind of connection to AWS from where you’re currently using your ARIN-assigned block, such as via a site-to-site tunnel or Direct Connect circuit, you could use one of your available ARIN IP addresses and NAT it to one of the AWS hosts’ private IP addresses rather than having a public IP address assigned directly by AWS.

You would also need to either set the default route on the shared route table to go back over the tunnel so you don’t create an asymmetrical route, or you could create a separate route table just for that VM and set the default route accordingly without affecting the routes your other VMs use.

It could be a bit messy to maintain if you do this all for multiple VMs, and you would have the potential bottleneck of the connections going through wherever your ARIN block is in use at, but it’s your call.